# Hexo blog punctuation marks

Tags: node.js, markdown, blogs, hexo

I start a blog with hexo. In the main content of a post hexo does not render punctuation marks like ë 's " " ( ) it override those caracters with an �

I installed "hexo-renderer-marked": "^0.3.2"
I run my blog from a cloud vps.

Anybody? �

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The md file was set to 1252 (ansi / latin) changing it to utf-8 and I got normal text.